# Имитация нажатия кнопки

Tags: jquery

Есть форма ввода: текстовое поле, кнопка. Как сделать так, чтобы форма отправлялась, даже если кнопка не нажата?
Пробовал `$(":submit").click();` не работает.

Comment: В смысле?

    $("form").submit();

Это нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.form').on('submit', function() {
 //your code
});

$('.form').trigger('submit');
```